# Can "Page Extraction Now Allowed" documents be processed with Tika?

Tags: java, apache-tika, text-analysis

I am using sample code of Apache tika to extract text from PDF documents. The thing is that when I select a portion of text in a paragraph in the PDF document and then right click the text to copy it, it shows up as wierd box characters when I paste the same text in a notepad.

The PDF document has a property named "Page Extraction" which is set to "Not Allowed".

Is there a way to handle PDF documents with this property value?

Also, is there anything else I need to take care of to handle that portion of text which is not even being copied manually properly.

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: It shows up junk characters as I wrote here

Comment: How are you calling Apache Tika? Is there a sample file publically available somewhere which shows up the problem? Did you try with the latest version of Apache Tika?